# In react, dropdown elements sometimes do not show up

Tags: reactjs, api, dropdown

I have already asked a question about related to this project once, and now I have run into another situation.

I am making a dropdown with multiselect-react-dropdown that must take the _id of the subjects that it is supposed to display, and pass it to the Express API.

It was working fine, with the issue that it did not display the options with their names, only their _ids, which was what was being called by this code:

```
async function listActiveSubjectsById() {
     const response = await api.get("/subject");
     const ids = response.data.subjects.map(({ _id }) => _id);
     return ids;
}
```

I needed it to show the subject name, but pass only it's ID to the API. A friend helped me out and it worked. This is what has been written as a result.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';


const TeacherClassInfo = props => {
    const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState();
    const [subjectName, setSubjectName] = useState();

    let selectedSubject = [];

    const onSelect = async (selectedList, selectedItem) => {
        let index = await subjectName.indexOf(selectedItem, 0);
        const getSubjects = await listActiveSubjectsById();
        let subjectsDict =[];
        getSubjects.forEach((value) => {
            subjectsDict.push(value);
        });
        selectedSubject.push(subjectsDict[index]);
    }

    const handleListActiveSubjects = async () => {
        setSubjects(subjectName);
    }

    const handleListActiveSubjectsName = async () => {
        const getSubjectsName = await listActiveSubjectsByName();
        setSubjectName(getSubjectsName);
    }

    useEffect((subjectName) => {
        handleListActiveSubjects();
        handleListActiveSubjectsName();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Multiselect
                options={subjects}
                isObject={false}
                onSelect={onSelect}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                placeholder={"Quais matérias você leciona? *"}
            />
```

The subject names are being called through this method:

```
async function listActiveSubjectsByName() {
    const response = await api.get("/materia");
    const names = response.data.subjects.map(({ name }) => name);
    return names;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the options show, and other times it does not show, as shown by the pictures:

[image: not working]

[image: working]

And I'm not sure what is causing it, but I think it has to something to do with the useEffect(), and I would like some help in identifying and correcting this problem, for it to always show.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you need both the name and the id, you could just return `response.data.subjects` directly to get a list of objects containing both the id and the name.

Comment: I did that before, but was unable to separate the ID from the rest of the fields after that. And the API only accepts the ID

Comment: Maybe you have to run the effect hook after the subjectName has changed. If you tried like this: useEffect(() => {
        if (!subjectName) return;
        handleListActiveSubjects();
        handleListActiveSubjectsName();
    }, [subjectName]);

Comment: Actually, I found out how to fix it. I just removed the empty [ ] by the end of the useEffect. I don't know if its the best action, but it is working for now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: And answering @tpliakas, it did work, but a warning is returned.



```React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleListActiveSubjects'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps```

Comment: without the dep array it will run on every render. you should add in the array your functions too

Comment: Forget what I said before. removing the [ ] does not pass anything to the api. But unfortunately 
```
useEffect(() => { if (!subjectName) return; handleListActiveSubjects(); handleListActiveSubjectsName(); }, [subjectName]);
```

also didn't work

Comment: It shows this error now:

```Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.```